# Object.Equals clarification in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, equals

I've made a simple test :

```
     object t = 3;
     object aa = 3;
#1   Console.WriteLine(t.Equals(aa));  
#2   Console.WriteLine(t.Equals(3));  
#3   Console.WriteLine(3.Equals(aa));
```

All of them are true.(that's my problem actually).

looking at `object`  , this is the used function:

```
 public virtual bool Equals(object obj);
```

The equals is virtual. so it can be overridden.

But I **don't** see  any polymorphic  behavior. this is just a pure boxed value.

- Regarding line #1 `t.Equals(aa)`

  The reference type is the static type - Object.

  so I thought it should call `Object.Equals` : which means that the reference are **different**  , meaning the first answer should be `False`.(and I probably wrong here). why is that?
- Regarding line #2 `t.Equals(3)`

  Again, `t's` static type is object. so `Object.Equals` is running. how come it is `true` ?
- Regarding line #3 `3.Equals(aa)`

  I believe it is the `public override bool Equals(object obj);` is running  because the static type is `in`t. and the param type is object. but why does it `true` ? does it un-box the value ?

*it seems that something , somehow unboxes the object without my notice :-(*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Object`s `Equals` method is polymorphic, so it can be overriden by subtypes like `int`. [Int32.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3wwa8z.aspx) overrides this method to do a value comparison between the current object and its argument, and since the arguments are equal once unboxed, it returns true.

There are two overload of `Int32.Equals` - `bool Equals(object)` and `bool Equals(int)`. The `bool Equals(object)` overload is the one overriden from `object`. Since `t` and `aa` are `object` references, this is the method which will be called in examples 1 and 2.

In example 3, it is still this overload which is called since `aa` is an `object` and this is therefore the only valid overload.

The `==` operator is static and is resolved statically based on the types of its arguments, which are both `object` in your example. The `==` operator for `object` compares references, and in this case will return false for two separate boxed ints.

Comment: in the first line ...which override is occurring ? this one `public override bool Equals(object obj);` but how ref can be equal to another ref ( I dont care they both hold 3)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - They will all call `Int32.Equals`, however this method does not check for reference equality, it will check the type of its argument is an `int`, unbox it and then compare its value to the current object (also a boxed int).

Comment: @RoyiNamir - There are two what? In the first two examples, the `Equals` method is called on `t`, and in the third it's the literal `3`.

Comment: In `int` there are 2 Equals. `public bool Equals(int obj);`public override bool Equals(object obj);`

Comment: @RoyiNamir The second one is what is being used to compare the values.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I've updated the answer explaining which overload will be chosen.

Comment: I have a problem with 2 words in the first paragraph: `once unboxed`.... why do they unboxed if the argument is still object ( in `bool Equals(object)`)

Comment: This is the correct answer but the mention of overloads is a red herring, as overloads don’t come into play here at all. The only method considered at compile time is `object.Equals`. Since overload resolution happens at compile time, `int.Equals` overloads are irrelevant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph can you please elaborate in an answer ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - The override of `Equals` in `int32` will have to unbox its argument once it has checked it's an `int`.

Comment: @Royi I don’t have anything to add to Kendall’s answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I agree that the overloads of `Int32.Equal` are not relevant, I only added them in response to an earlier question.

Comment: So int.Equals(object) by its design is unboxing the object....right ? cause this is the part which caused me a headache.

Answer (score 5):

The virtual method `Object.Equals` is being called, but because of the way virtual methods work, it calls the `Int32.Equals` method instead, which compares the `int` values, not the references.

**Virtual methods are bound at runtime.** That is, they choose the appropriate method at runtime, not at compile time. In this case, `Object.Equals` is what is in the compiled code, but since you're comparing `int`s, it chooses `Int32.Equals` at runtime. This is accomplished using something called v-tables (in case you wanted to read more on this).

Keep in mind that `Equals` is supposed to act like this, and if you really want reference equality, you can use `ReferenceEquals`.

Note that this doesn't have anything to do with boxing. You'll get the same behaviour with, for example, a `string`, or a custom class.

Comment: But I didnt see any `Object t = new Int32()` here ( polymorphic) it's just a pure box value.....mmmm?

Comment: What's the difference between `new Int32()` and `0`? *A: None*

Comment: this line `object t = 3;` is not boxing ? sure it is

Comment: Yes, it is boxing. But the fact that it is boxing is irrelevent to the answer.

Comment: This line is boxing the `int` value. That still leaves the `int` at runtime, that's why the `Int32.Equals()` is called.

Comment: `new Int32()` will yield 0 cause its the default value. what about 3 ?

Comment: 3 is the `Int32` value 3, much like 0, but 3. What's your question?

Comment: if `Object t = new Int32()` is like `object t=0` (default value)  , so what is the relative code  for `object t=3`  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir There is none. `Int32` only supports the default constructor. Why does it matter? It's all the same in the end.

Comment: The only thing which I dont understand is `which compares the int values, not the references` why does he unbox the objects ? the argument of this method is OBJECT not INT. and (object)3 <> (object)3

Comment: It unboxes the objects because it wants to compare the values, not the references. Remember, `Equals` does value comparison.

Comment: so you're telling me that behind the scenes it does `if (obj is int)...`? cause I couldnt find this line in decompile.

Comment: To determine which virtual override to call, it uses v-tables, as I mentioned in my answer. I don't understand all the details, but I'm sure Google does.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question the following Asserts will all pass

```
[Test] 
public void EqualityOnInts()
{
    object a = 1;
    object b = 1;

    Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    Assert.IsTrue(1.Equals(a));
    Assert.IsTrue(b.Equals(1));
}
```

If you instantiate `a` you create a new `integer` object with value 1. Calling the `Equals` method on `a` will result in calling the `Equals` method on `Int32`. Also, if you do `a.GetType() it will return`Int32`.

Since the `Equals` implementation of `Int32` will check if the value is equal, and does not care about a different object reference, the result will be "true".